# Install Meson and Ninja (one removes the other)

Tags: ninja, meson-build

I want to install [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp)

Instructions to reproduce:

1. Install both `meson` (which requires Python3) and `ninja`.
2. When I run `sudo apt-get install meson ninja` I get the following results:

```bash
$ sudo apt-get install meson ninja
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
meson : Depends: ninja-build but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am trying to install `ninja` which removes `meson`, and installing `meson` removes `ninja`, with the above error. Does anyone know what to do about this?

Answer (score 1):

The correct Debian package for the `ninja` build system is `ninja-build`.

`sudo apt-get install meson ninja-build`